# Low fps due to [Unaccounted time between & Graphics.PresentAndSync] using Vuforia with Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have recently decided to upgrade to **Vuforia** *6.2.10* and also update to **Unity** *5.6.1f1.*
I am currently working on a project for our customer, however I have encountered a big problem with the above mentioned setup.

Description:

When the application runs on the **Unity** editor in Windows it is really smooth and everything works as expected (also tested on the **Unity** profiler). When the application is built for an **Android** device the fps drops to 10-20 depending on the device. Using the **Unity** profiler to look at the problem in more detail (see attached photo). I have noticed two big issues:

- There is an unknown process called: *Unaccounted time between: InputProcess and InputProcess*
- There is a known process causing big lag spikes, lowering the fps called: *Graphics.PresentAndSync*

In the photo you can see those two processes combined are taking in total **70%** (sometimes more) of the device's CPU power. I did not have this issue with previous **Vuforia** versions.

Could you help me resolve this problem?

---

### Steps to reproduce the issue

1. Update **Unity** to release: *5.6.1f1.*
2. Create an empty project (3D).
3. Delete the Camera and Light from the scene (to make it completely empty).
4. Download and import **Vuforia** SDK version: *6.2.10*.
5. Drag the AR Camera prefab into the scene in **Unity**.
6. Enter the license in the **Vuforia** configuration in **Unity**.
7. Build and Run on an **Android** device.

### Android devices tested

- Lenovo k3 Note (~13 fps).
- Xiaomi Redmi 4A (~15 fps).
- Samsung Galaxy S5 (~20 fps).
- Lenovo Phab 2.0 Pro (~30 fps).

**PS:** There is a very similar issue on the **Vuforia** dev. forums, however the solution offered did not help. The post can be found here: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/graphicspresentandsync

**PSS:** Quality settings for the project are as low as possible.

Profiler photo:
[image]

Comment: No code?  Likely no answer

Comment: @MickyD Read steps to reproduce please...

Comment: You'd better ask on Vuforia's forum. Even if I know that it's crap. Here is made to help you with code. You don't provide code? You can't really help you.

Comment: The performance problems stuff is really hard to troubleshoot without access to the project and those devices with low fps.

Comment: @Programmer True, however the devices with high fps still have the same issue, only problem is you don't notice it since the processing power is better. What I want to understand is if this problem is occurring because of the combination of version from **Vuforia** and **Unity**, since previously it did not happen on same devices tested.

Comment: @Andromelus I don't really understand what you meant to say. This site is not purely for questions about code. My problem is not related to code that I have written, in fact as I stated I have not written any code to produce this issue, so how could I paste my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151396/discussion-between-hristo-and-mickyd).

Comment: Here is a recent post on their forum, describing similar problems with the versions you mentioned _"[I am also facing this issue using **Unity 5.6.0f3** and **Vuforia 6.2.10**.    So far I've seen a lot of people report this issue and both Unity and Vuforia haven't contacted or replied about it. Also, no developer has posted any sort of workaround, fix or solution, which seems strange due to how old some of these reports are](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/issues-and-bugs/camera-lags-android)"_

Comment: @MickyD Hey, I also found that thread a few days ago, however I think those guys have a problem with the input field in Unity and the Vuforia SDK. It might be that the problems are related, but devs. @ Vuforia are stubborn and don't respond... I have no Idea who to blame. Is it Unity or Vuforia? :D

Comment: Haha yes not sure.  I hope someone provides a fix.  Wishing you well.  :)